# secure_file_priv に指定されているディレクトリにファイルを移動したが、依然引っかかる

Tags: mysql

table にファイルをロードする際、`--secure-file-priv option` に引っかかるので、

```
show variables like "secure_file_priv";
```

で出力された `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\` に目的のファイル (filename.csv) を入れ、

```
load data infile 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\filename.csv' into table tablename;
```

としたが、依然 `--secure-file-priv option` に引っかかります。なぜでしょうか。

エラーコード：

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` はエスケープ用に使われる文字なので `\\` と書いてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
mysql> select 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\filename.csv';
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| C:ProgramDataMySQLMySQL Server 8.0Uploadsfilename.csv |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| C:ProgramDataMySQLMySQL Server 8.0Uploadsfilename.csv |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\filename.csv';

+------------------------------------------------------------+
| C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\filename.csv |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\filename.csv |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: こちらの回答のように修正すると無事ファイルを LOAD できました。
具体的には
 mysql> load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\filename.csv' into table tablename;
 としました。（MySQL 上では \ は 円マークで表示されます）